# my LSTM time-series forecast predictions have a shift to the future

Tags: time-series, lstm, forecasting, shift

I am trying to make predcitions on a time-series data (univariate) using Tensorflow. However, when I see the results, the predictions have a time shift (please see the figure). Anyone ideas what the problem is?

Below is the function I use to prepare the set of inputs and outputs (X and Y) as well as normalizing the data

```
# define a fucntion to prepare the X and Y for training the model
def df_to_X_y_group(df_as_np, window_size, num): # input is numpy array. j_start and j_end show the features, num is the number of wavelength in a group 
   X=[] # make an empty list
   y=[]
   for  j in range(0,df_as_np.shape[1]-num,num): #(start, stop, step). defining a window over features of size num wihtout any overlaps 
       for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size): # there is overlap between windows in time
           row=[a for a in df_as_np[i:i+window_size, j:j+num]] 
           X.append(row)
           label=[r for r in df_as_np[i+window_size, j:j+num]]
           y.append(label)
       
   return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# convert the data to X and y format 

window_size_group=50
output_group=2
num=2

X_group , y_group= df_to_X_y_group(df_as_np, window_size_group, num) # 70085 rows (number of training samples), 6 is the size of the window (number of time steps) and 5 is the number of features
X_group.shape , y_group.shape

# Split the data to train, val and test by 70,20 and 10% of the data
X_train_group , y_train_group = X_group[:int(.7 * X_group.shape[0])], y_group[:int(.7 * X_group.shape[0])]
X_val_group , y_val_group = X_group[int(.7 * X_group.shape[0]):int(.9 * X_group.shape[0])] , y_group[int(.7 * X_group.shape[0]):int(.9 * X_group.shape[0])]
X_test_group , y_test_group = X_group[int(.9 * X_group.shape[0]):] , y_group[int(.9 * X_group.shape[0]):]

# Normalize the data
X_train_mean_group = np.mean(X_train_group)
X_train_std_group = np.std(X_train_group)

def preprocess_group(X):
   X_norm = (X - X_train_mean_group) / X_train_std_group
   return X_norm

# Now convert the data back to before normalization
def postprocess_group(pred):
   actual = (pred * X_train_std_group) + X_train_mean_group
   return actual

# apply the preprocess to the inputs and outputs
X_train_norm_group=preprocess_group(X_train_group)
X_val_norm_group=preprocess_group(X_val_group)
X_test_norm_group=preprocess_group(X_test_group)

y_train_norm_group=preprocess_group(y_train_group)
y_val_norm_group=preprocess_group(y_val_group)
y_test_norm_group=preprocess_group(y_test_group)

X_train_group.shape , y_train_group.shape , X_val_group.shape , y_val_group.shape , X_test_group.shape , y_test_group .shape
```

Here is the model:

```
# Build the model

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint # to save the model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Huber
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


model_group=Sequential()

model_group.add(InputLayer((X_group.shape[1],X_group.shape[2]))) # size of the input (windows (time steps) of size 6 and 1024 features )
model_group.add(LSTM(128))
model_group.add(Dense(20, 'relu'))
model_group.add(Dense(output_group))
model_group.summary()

# Train the model
cp2=ModelCheckpoint('model/group/overlapnum2' , save_best_only=True) # it saves the best model based on val error
model_group.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])
model_group.fit(X_train_norm_group, y_train_norm_group, validation_data=(X_val_norm_group, y_val_norm_group), epochs=15, , callbacks=[cp2])
```

Below is the function to predict and plot the data:

```
# We make a function which predict and plot 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse
def plot_predictions(model, X, y, start=0, end=100):
    predictions = model.predict(X[start:end])
    predictions_actual=postprocess(predictions)
    
    y_actual=postprocess(y[start:end])
        
    plt.plot(predictions_actual, c='r', label='Predictions')
    plt.plot(y_actual, label= 'Actuals')
    
    plt.xlabel("Order of the data (TIme)")
    plt.ylabel("Number of Photons")
    
    plt.legend() # so the label shows up
    return mse(y_actual, predictions_actual)

# plot
plot_predictions(model, X_test_norm, y_test_norm, start=0, end=300)
```

Here is the predcitions results which are shifted in time (for the true results, y(t) should be replaced with y(t+1)):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnZtp.png)

I have tried tuning several hyperparameters such as batch size, window size, or adding layers but none of these helped.